# iOS: What does gamut have to do with the axis of a UIStackView?

Tags: ios, uistackview

To add a trait variation for a certain size class on a stack view I am making, this Gamut attribute appears. What is it for and what it does do? How is it related to stack views?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add that variation to many elements of many view types in the Interface Builder -- add a `UIView` and click the `+` button next to some of its characteristics and you will see the same dialog. It allows you to change aspects of your interface based on different characteristics of the device. So if the device has a compact width, do something special.

`Gamut` lets you change characteristics of the layout based on whether the device shows "wide color" (`P3`) or not. In this case, the `Gamut` setting would likely not be relevant to the axis. But you might want to choose a different axis based on whether the width was `Regular` and the height was `Regular`, for example.

Comment: You would probably only vary based on gamut for color and images properties, but programmers love to use the same hammer on every screw—even the programmers that write Xcode.